# Deleting a section from an array

Tags: c, arrays

I have two example functions for deleting a section of an array

the first uses memmove, will this approach cause problems when it comes to freeing the memory allocated for the input array (the input array is always malloc'd, e.g. its on the heap)?

The input array of doubles has been malloc'd prior to the call to this function. This function is trying to delete values in the array, e.g. make a standard array look a little like a dynamic array. However, does the memmove call mean that when the input array is subsequently freed (outside of this function after this function has returned) then the call to free may not work correctly due to the fact that the array has been modified?

```
/**
 * Remove a contiguous section of data from an array of doubles
 */
void dbl_array_del(double *array, size_t *plen_array, size_t idx, size_t n_elems)
{
    size_t len_array = *plen_array;

    /* must delete at least one value */
    assert(n_elems > 0);
    /* section to remove does not exceed the length of the array */
    assert(idx+n_elems <= len_array); 
    /* function cannot create an 'empty' array */
    assert(len_array-n_elems > 0);

   if ( (idx+n_elems) == len_array) {
        /* case where section to be removed reaches end of array, no memory has
         * to be shifted, only array length altered */
        len_array-=n_elems;
    } else {
        /* otherwise data to right of section has to be shifted left, back over
         * removed section */
        memmove(array+idx, array+idx+n_elems,
                (len_array-idx-n_elems)*sizeof(double));
        len_array-=n_elems;
    }            
    *plen_array = len_array;
}
```

the 2nd approach doesn't use memmove, instead it iterates over the values that need shifting left. Is this a safer approach in terms of memory leaks?

```
/**
 * Remove a contiguous section of data from an array of doubles
 */
void dbl_array_del(double *array, size_t *plen_array, size_t idx, size_t n_elems)
{
    size_t len_array = *plen_array;

    /* must delete at least one value */
    assert(n_elems > 0);
    /* section to remove does not exceed the length of the array */
    assert(idx+n_elems <= len_array); 
    /* function cannot create an 'empty' array */
    assert(len_array-n_elems > 0);

    /* n is the no. of values that need shifting left */
    size_t n = len_array-(idx+n_elems);
    size_t i;
    /* shift values left */
    for (i=idx; i<idx+n; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i+n_elems];
    }
    /* reset values off end of array */
    for (i=idx+n; i<len_array; i++) {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
    *plen_array = len_array-n_elems;
}
```

Comment: Am not sure memory leaks is your primary problem here.

Comment: Since neither version allocates memory on its own, memory leaks do not come into the picture at all. It's quite unclear what kind of problems you believe might arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memmove does not hurt your call to free(). It basically is just your for-Loop hidden in a function (probably with some machine-specific optimization).

If a block has been allocated using malloc(), your system remembers how many items to de-allocate when you call free() on the returned pointer. That does not change when you alter the contents of your array, either using memmove() or your self-written for loop.

Comment: thanks - this is exactly the confirmation I was looking for, that the memmove is will not affect the free.. my brain seizes from time to time on memory management issues

Comment: If you want to reclaim the memory, you'd have to realloc(3) the array. But that is another kettle of fish...

Comment: @vonbrand how do you mean? freeing the input array after the call to adbl_array_del() will be sufficient to free all alloc'd heap memory - the underlying c array is the same length throughout - it just has its contents moved around to make it 'appear' smaller. no realloc necessary..

Answer (score 0):

In terms of safety, your best bet is to not use raw C arrays like this at all. std::vector provides a mechanism to safely manage (resize/delete/relocate/etc...) the underlying data.

That said, in your example above, either solution is going to allow you to overwrite memory. In terms of safety there is no better way. In terms of performance, the memmove solution could have a tailored implementation that *could* be faster than moving an element at a time manually.

Comment: yes C only i'm afraid - this is a situation where switching to a 'proper' dynamic array would prob be overkill - need a hack just to make it appear that some values have been deleted